# Atom linter doesn't recognize classes in the same package

Tags: java, package, atom-editor, linter

I currently have the `linter` package (here: `apm install linter`) and the `linter-javac` package (here: `apm install linter-javac`). It works great for the most part, but when I try to use packages, it doesn't recognize classes in the same package, like so:

Tree:

bank

- Account.java
- Account.class
- AccountManager.java

Account.java:

```
package bank;

public class Account {}
```

AccountManager.java:

```
package bank;

public class AccountManager {
    private Account[] accounts;
}
```

When I declare the `Account[]` in `AccountManager.java`, it is underlined red and noted `cannot find symbol`.

Testing the classes, they do work and compile via terminal but not through atom and they are still showing the error. How can I fix this?

(note: the same problem occurs with `ide-java` package)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is just an issue with the `linter-javac` package. The real solution is moving away from Atom.